# local notification in an application

Tags: ios, timezone, uilocalnotification

I am stuck with the strange problem. I am making an alarm application.When i fire a local notification it works fine in simulator but when I compile the code in an iPhone it dose not working.Same code is working on an simulator and not responding on a iPhone.

 notification code:

```
-(void) scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate
{

 UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

 localNotif.fireDate = fireDate;
 localNotif.alertBody = @"Time to wake Up";
 localNotif.alertAction = @"Show me";
 localNotif.soundName = @"Tick-tock-sound.mp3";
 localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
 localNotif.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear;


 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];


}
```

and save button code is:

```
- (IBAction)saveBtn:(id)sender {


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

    NSLog(@"time is %@",dateFormatter.timeZone);
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    NSString * dateTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timePicker.date];
    datesArray = @[[dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.timePicker.date]];
}
```

Please tell me the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this code in appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    


 if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
            UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                            UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                            UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                                     categories:nil];
            [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
            [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
        } else {
            // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
            [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                             UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                             UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
        }
return Yes;
}
```